# Angular2 *ngFor setting index as attribute inside same tag

Tags: indexing, angular, ngfor

im trying to create a bootstrap carousel. So i use *ngFor for adding the elements and the carousel-indicators.(little circles indicating current position)

```
<li data-target="#myCarousel" *ngFor="#item of items; #idx = index"  data-slide-to="idx" [class.active]="idx === 0" >
```

I am setting the active class entry by [class.active]="idx === 0" and it works fine.
But when i am trying to set data-slide-to="idx" the result is not the wanted index as number but the string "idx".

Any idea how to assign the index-value ?

Answer (score 5):

You have two options here:

**1. Bind directly to the attribute**

```js
[attr.data-slide-to]="idx"
```

**2. Use string interpolation**

```js
attr.data-slide-to="{{idx}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding requires `[]` or `{{}}`. Binding to attributes needs the `attr.` prefix

```
[attr.data-slide-to]="idx"
```